# Google Analytics Data API v1 (impressions) data does not match with GA4 Analytics / Ads data

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I want to retrieve Google Ads related data (impressions, clicks, cost) from a GA4 Google Analytics property (linked to my Google Ads account) using the new Google Analytics Data API v1. My code works, but it returns very different numbers compared to what I see in Google Analytics or Google Ads.  For example for the week of 15-21 May:

|  | My code using GA Data API v1 | Google Analytics | Google Ads |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Impressions | 2472 | ? | 4.17K |
| Clicks | 324 | 339 | 353 |
| Cost | 92.3 | 95.7 | 98.23 |

As you can see there is a **very big difference especially for the number of impressions**. (Unfortunately I could not find a way to check this number in Analytics for a large number of campaigns as "Exploration reports" only work for 10 campaigns or so.) I see similar differences for all other weeks.

Please see below my php code retrieving the data from Analytics. What am I doing wrong that I'm not getting the same (impression) numbers as in Google Analytics/Ads?

```
public function handle()
{

    $downloader = new GNGGA4DataDownloader();
    $results = $downloader->run('2023-05-15', '2023-05-21', config('services.google-analytics.propertyID'));

    $ti = 0;
    $tcl = 0;
    $tco = 0; 

    foreach ($results as $r) {
        $ti += $r->impressions;
        $tcl += $r->clicks;
        $tco += $r->cost;
    }

    dd($results, 'impressions: ' . $ti, 'clicks: ' . $tcl, 'cost: ' . $tco);

}
```

---

```
    <?php
namespace App\GNG;

use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\OrderBy;
use stdClass;

//This is the current API to download Analytics data from GA4 properties.
class GNGGA4DataDownloader 
{

    private function downloadData($startDate, $endDate, $ga_propertyID) {

        $path = storage_path('app/GA/GNG GA4 API-XXX.json');
        putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=" . $path);

        $client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

        // Make an API call.
        $response = $client->runReport([
            'property' => 'properties/' . $ga_propertyID,
            'dateRanges' => [
                new DateRange([
                    'start_date' => $startDate,
                    'end_date' => $endDate,
                ]),
            ],
            'dimensions' => [
                new Dimension(['name' => 'sessionCampaignName']),
                new Dimension(['name' => 'year']),
                new Dimension(['name' => 'isoWeek']),
            ],
            'metrics' => [
                new Metric(['name' => 'advertiserAdImpressions']), 
                new Metric(['name' => 'advertiserAdClicks']), 
                new Metric(['name' => 'advertiserAdCost']), 
                
            ],
            'orderBys' => [
                new OrderBy([
                    'dimension' => new OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy([
                        'dimension_name' => 'sessionCampaignName', 
                        'order_type' => OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy\OrderType::ALPHANUMERIC
                    ]),
                    'desc' => false,
                ]),
            ],
            'keepEmptyRows' => true,  
            
        ]);

        return $response;


    }

    private function extractResults($response) {

        $results = array();

        foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {

            $d = new stdClass();

            $d->campaignCode = $row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue();
            $d->isoYear = $row->getDimensionValues()[1]->getValue();
            $d->isoWeek = $row->getDimensionValues()[2]->getValue();
            
            $d->impressions = $row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue();
            $d->clicks = $row->getMetricValues()[1]->getValue();
            $d->cost = $row->getMetricValues()[2]->getValue();
         
            array_push($results, $d);

        }

        return $results;

    }
    
    function run($startDate, $endDate, $gaPropertyID) {

        $response = $this->downloadData($startDate, $endDate, $gaPropertyID);

        $results = $this->extractResults($response);

        return $results;

    }

}
```

[image: Numbers in Google Ads]

[image: Numbers in Google Analytics]

Comment: Im suprised it works mixing alpha and beta

Comment: The reports dont match remove year and isoWeek  looks like you have five metrics in the report on GA and only three in the report you are extracting from the api they need to be the same.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo: Thanks for the hints. Regarding your first comment: The first "use" line with "V1alpha" was not used for anything, now I removed it. Regarding your second comment: I believe, I use 3 dimensions (CampaignCode, IsoYear, IsoWeek) and 3 metrics (impressions, clicks, cost). Where do you see 5 metrics? Thanks!

Comment: in the report from ga that you are comparing to